# SSH, connect and exec mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql, unix, ssh

i`m using mysql client

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

how i can run connect on SSH tunnel?

---

i create ssh connect use `SharpSsh`

```
SshExec exec = new SshExec("host", "user");
exec.Password = "pass";

Console.Write("Connect...");
exec.Connect(22);
Console.WriteLine("OK");
string output = exec.RunCommand("mysql -p pass -u user db -h host;");
if (output == "")
   Console.WriteLine("error");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

But why do I write a lot of code that can, through the client can immediately make a ssh connection, right?

please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening a shell over SSH, you should just use port forwarding.  Follow the [port forwarding example](http://www.tamirgal.com/home/SourceView.aspx?Item=SharpSSH&File=PortForwardingL.cs) on the SharpSSH homepage.  There is no need to run the `mysql` command on the remote server at all.

The magic line in the example is this:

```
session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
```

It will create a tunnel from port `lport` on the local machine to port `rport` on `rhost`.  Once the tunnel is up, simply connect the `MySqlClient` with a connection string using *localhost* and *lport*.  Even though you are connecting to the local machine, the connection will be forwarded to the remote end through the tunnel.